# Listbox not showing items

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I want my items list in a listbox but when i try

```
listbox1.Items.Add("Item1");
```

nothing is being added but
if i place the code in the forms load metod it works but when I call it from the
separate code module it does not. I think this is because another instance
of the form is being updated. 
but how do i get the active form and then add the items.
I got a Abstract class and tree subclasses and i want my subclasses in a list and then showed on the form.

this was my first attempt but this dosent work.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Subclass o = new Subclass();
        List<BaseClass> l = new List<BaseClass>();
        l.Add(o);

        Form1 f = new Form1();
        f.AddObjectToListbox(l);          
}
```

And then in my From1 i got

```
public void AddObjectToListbox(List<BaseClass> l)
{
        foreach (Subclass objectname in l.OfType<Subclass>())
        {
             l.Items.Insert(0, "text" + O.getMetod);                 
        }
}
```

but like it is now it just add to another instance of form1.
thanks for alle the help.

Comment: Show us some code. It's hard to see how your code works and what instances are made.

Comment: Please show the code where you want to add an item from outside the form hosting your listbox.

Comment: sorry for my bad explanation of my question. just want it solved as soon as possible. and I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suddenly you find what you was looking for yourself.
this did it.

```
Form currentForm = Form.ActiveForm;
ListBox lb = (ListBox)currentForm.Controls.Find("ListboxName", true)[0];
```

but still thanks for looking at my question.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a litle bit vague...where are you calling listbox1.Items.Add("Item1"); from

e.g.

From a method in the Forms class file

From code in another file,

From code in a different assembly,

However, you can get the Active Form via the Form class static method:

System.Windows.Forms.Form.ActiveForm

May this helps

Comment: first i tryed to make the metod static but then i cant use the listbox controle ?

Answer (score 0):

One problem might be the use of "Object" as both a class *and* variable name in the AddObjectToListBox method.
Also if you are casting obj to Subclass, but then assign it to a variable of type Object, that is not making much sense. You could solve both of these at once, like this.

```
foreach (Subclass obj in l.OfType<Subclass>())
{
     lbVehicles.Items.Insert(0, "text" + obj.getMetod);                 
}
```

As a third, it looks like you're creating a new form every time the button is clicked, is that intentional?

Comment: yes okay could see I had written my example a little too quickly of cause there cant stand object in both places. but This is just a sample of my code. and yes im creating a new form every time because i dident know how to get the active form. and like i said in my eksempel i think that is why it is not working

Answer (score -5):

First try to clear items and then try to add